# Bind menu items to a list

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a list of strings that holds the names of menu items:

```
List<string> namesStorage;
```

How do I bind this list as collection in XAML?
Right now I have wrote this is part, which already works:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <MenuItem Header="MenuItem1" Command="{Binding Command1}" />
    <MenuItem Header="MenuItem2" Command="{Binding Command1}" />
</StackPanel>
```

This items must have one command (different arguments will be set in the view model).
But I think this is not a good way to set every `MenuItem` in XAML - It is ok now for two items but I wonder how to make a universal decision for any number of this menu items. I have created a list that holds names but how to bind it (and keep a commands)?

Comment: for binding `namesStorage` needs to be a public property

Comment: yes, I have done it already

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After setting the correct DataContext, this should work:

```
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding namesStorage}" x:Name="ItemsControlName">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding}" Command="{Binding ElementName=ItemsControlName, Path=DataContext.Command1}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

**Edit**: Removed Parent-Stackpanel as suggested in the comments

Comment: The StackPanel should be in the ItemsControl's ItemsPanel property instead of wrapping the ItemsControl if you want to display stacked items

Comment: Both possibilities work quite fine for me - what's the real difference between placing the itemscontrol in a stackpanel or using the Itemspanel property?

Comment: The StackPanel here will stack its children. Its only children is ItemsControl here, so it'll only stack the ItemsControl. It visually work because ItemsControl already use a StackPanel as its ItemsPanel.

Comment: the command is not working for me(  In upper control I have set command with Command="{Binding Vrapper.myViewModel.MyCommand }" but this not helped. My DataContext is  d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=vm:MainViewModel}"  The Vrapper is in MainViewModel. What I have done wrong?

Comment: @curiousity The DataContext of the `MenuItem` is no longer that, since it is inside an ItemsControl. Its DataContext is the `string` object. So you need to use `ElementName`, as Philip suggests, or `RelativeSource`, to get the Command from another DataContext (in this case, the ItemsControl DataContext which is your ViewModel)

Comment: According to what you said, this would be the correct code, I guess: `Command="{Binding ElementName=ItemsControlName, Path=DataContext.Vrapper.myViewModel.MyCommand}"`

Comment: Also, I agree with @nkoniishvt. Using a StackPanel outside an ItemsControl won't have any effect over how the items inside are displayed. If you want to modify how the items are displayed, you have to use the ItemsPanel property, but it isn't necessary in this case because ItemsControl already uses a StackPanel by default... For what it's worth, I'd remove the StackPanel from the answer.

Comment: Thank you Almulo!! Also I have removed stack panel